# Cannot Instantiate Any Google Play Services XML Widgets

Tags: xml, google-play-services, android

So I'm trying to enhance my Android application by adding various Google Play Services to it.  I imported the latest library as it says on the Google Developer page and can use any of the functions and objects within the java portion.  But, my problem is when I try to reference that same library in the xml.  Each time I get:

"The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton"

The error log:
"com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton failed to instantiate.
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 15"

Each time I run it, Eclipse crashes and it says the VM has stopped (GC Overhead limit). I've tried downgrading the Java, using different libraries externally, ect.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me.wikiplay"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/title_bar_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.me.wikiplay.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

XML Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- sign-out button -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Out"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what the deal is?  Is there anything I am doing wrong or need to change to get this to work?